# What does using 'Login with Facebook' or 'Facebook Connect' to login to another site allow the site to do?

Tags: facebook, security, login

When I use a Facebook account to login to another website, **what does 'logging in with Facebook' allow that website do with my Facebook account?**

Can they post messages on my wall or news feed or anything else that might be considered unwanted, especially if it is without permission?

*Edit:* after having another look around, I found an authentication message for another app that said "... may post status messages, notes, photos and videos to my Wall" - can apps do this without separate permission before the post is made?

Can apps ever push any kind of messages to my friends (and can they do this without asking at any point)?

Is there any way for others to tell what services I use Facebook to login with by looking at my profile?

**How can I tell if a website that I create an account with through Facebook will post my full name on their site?**

I assume that all of this would differ based on different implementations, but would I always be able to tell what I am getting myself into by looking at the 'Request for permissions' page?

Comment: I think it's better to be specific for Facebook in this question.. and maybe another one for goolge, twitter, etc.. :) looking forward for the facebook answer..

Comment: Your title, your body and your tags are asking for different items , could you please edit two of them to reflect the one for which you want the answer.

Comment: Okay, I have made some changes that took a while and separated the questions where I thought I should - let me know if you think it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all Extended Permission [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)
publish_stream will be required if the site want to post something on your wall, otherwise will throw an error with message

> (#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you click that you accept their terms, make sure that you read them.  Some sites will post status updates on your wall, others will store your information from facebook.  Make sure you trust the site that you use facebook login with, and always read the Extended Permissions like Ntf said.