# Explanation of Facebook Connect and 'Login with Facebook'?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I had previously thought that Facebook Connect and 'Login with Facebook' were separate things, but after reading this I changed my mind:

> ... features of Connect (login, profile integration, Feed, friend linking) ...
>
> From: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Facebook_Connect_Live_Sites

Is it correct that 'Login with Facebook' is a subset of Facebook connect?

What exactly are those features of connect - eg what does 'feed' entail?

How can I tell which features of Connect an app is using when I sign in with Facebook? Would it all be contained in the 'Request for permission' dialog?

Comment: Facebook Connect [FAQ](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=730) page.

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/what-does-using-login-with-facebook-or-facebook-connect-to-login-to-another-s

Answer (score 1):

Under the new Graph API, login using Facebook uses Connect.

Answer (score 0):

As for my experience 'login with facebook' uses facebook information and logs in. 'Connect' can update facebook status and do other stuff with facebook. Currently there is no way to edit application permissions in detail

Answer (score -1):

If you know something about Facebook development, SO you can understand about the Facebook API and Facebook connect. Facebook connect is a functionality by which we can Facebook profile data with the app or website, Mostly people use Facebook connect for registration process...

Well If you would like to learn more about Facebook connect you should learn about how Facebook connect can work below I am going to share some links where you can learn how website using Facebook connect.

- [Facebook Connect: Why and how to use it on your website](http://www.chewie.co.uk/general/facebook-connect-why-and-how-to-use-it-on-your-website/)
- [Benefits of Implementing Facebook Connect](http://www.cygnismedia.com/blog/implementing-facebook-connect/)

Hope now you can understand how Fb connect works..